# Clojure - Combine two lists by index

Tags: clojure

How would I combine two lists say `'(1 2 3 4)` and `'(:a :b :c :d)` to get 
`(1 :a 2 :b 3 :c 4 :d)`

As I can't just do `concat` as that would add the second list to the end of the first list.

I thought about doing something like

```
user=> (def a '(1 2 3 4))

user=> (def b '(:a :b :c :d))

user=> (def x (apply conj (second (split-at 1 a)) (nth b 0) (reverse (first (split-at 1 a)))))
(1 :a 2 3 4)

user=> (def y (apply conj (second (split-at 3 x)) (nth b 1) (reverse (first (split-at 3 x)))))
(1 :a 2 :b 3 4)

user=> (def z (apply conj (second (split-at 5 y)) (nth b 2) (reverse (first (split-at 5 y)))))
(1 :a 2 :b 3 :c 4)

user=> (def q (apply conj (second (split-at 7 z)) (nth b 3) (reverse (first (split-at 7 z)))))
(1 :a 2 :b 3 :c 4 :d)
```

But I think there is a better way

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to `interleave`:

```
(mapcat list '(1 2 3 4) '(:a :b :c :d))
;;=> (1 :a 2 :b 3 :c 4 :d)
```

Here `mapcat` is effectively doing the `cat` operation after the double `map` operation has correctly ordered the elements, albeit in list tuples, so `'(1 :a)` etc.

More explicitly:

```
(apply concat (map list '(1 2 3 4) '(:a :b :c :d))))
;;=> (1 :a 2 :b 3 :c 4 :d)
```

Thus if your first list really is increasing integer values then you don't have to generate them:

```
(apply concat (map-indexed list '(:a :b :c :d)))
;;=> (0 :a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`interleave`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/interleave):

```
(interleave '(1 2 3 4) '(:a :b :c :d))
=> (1 :a 2 :b 3 :c 4 :d)
```